# How are custom controls instantiated in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

My understanding is that when a component or custom control is defined in an aspx page using the `<%Register%>` tag, it is declared in an auto-generated designer.cs (C#) file by the compiler.   If this custom control is never used in the aspx page, does this still happen in the designer.cs file?

Assuming the control is used in the aspx page, what mechanism then instantiates this control, how is it new-ed up behind the scenes?  The designer file only declares it.  Thanks much, and if there are good articles out there discussing this I’d be happy to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not answer all your questions, but some of them.  Rick Strahl wrote a great article a while back on compilation and deployment that describes how it works:

[Compilation and Deployment in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp)

I added part of the article that I think relates most to your question below:

**Referencing other Pages and Controls**

Remember that page and control compilation happens on a per directory basis! So referencing other pages and controls becomes a little more tricky for ASP.NET 2.0, because you can no longer assume that a CodeBeside class from another page or control is available in the current assembly. At best all pages and controls in the same directory end up in the same assembly, at worst each page or control gets its own assembly and they know nothing about each other.

If you need to reference another page from a control or another page you need to explicitly import it with the @Reference directive. Again this is different than ASP.NET 1.1 where all CodeBehind classes were immediately available to your entire Web application. In ASP.NET 2.0 an explicit assembly reference is required to load it.

Assume for a minute that you have the DataEntry.aspx page I showed earlier and you want to create a second page that uses the same CodeBeside class so you can reuse the page logic, but change the page layout in DataEntry2.aspx by changing a few colors and moving around the controls of the page. In essence you want to have two ASPX pages reference the same CodeBeside file.

Here’s how to do this:

```
<%@ Reference Page="~/DataEntry.aspx" %>    
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="DataEntry" %>
```

I’m leaving out the CodeFile attribute reference the CodeBeside class of the DataEntry page, and add the @Reference tag to the page to force the CodeBeside class to be imported.

The same is true with any User Control definitions. To import a user control you need to use the @Register tag, which imports the assembly that the control lives in. ASP.NET is smart during compilation and figures out exactly where related assemblies live based on how the project is compiled. If the control or page lives in the same assembly no reference is actually added. But if it is external – in another directory for example, then the assembly reference is added.

**Referencing problems**

If you can explicitly reference other pages and controls in your markup pages, then all works well and as expected. But if you dynamically load controls or reference pages dynamically in your code, things get a lot more complicated.

The most common problem I run into is dynamic loading of controls. In ASP.NET 1.x you might have run code like this for dynamically loading controls into a page:

```
public partial class DynamicControlLoading : System.Web.UI.Page    
{    
    protected CustomUserControl MessageDisplay = null;  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {    
        MessageDisplay = this.LoadControl( "~/UserControls/CustomUserControl.ascx")   as CustomUserControl;

        this.Controls.Add(MessageDisplay);

    }

    protected void btnSay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {    
        this.MessageDisplay.ShowMessage(this.txtMessage.Text);

    }

}
```

CustomUserControl in this case is a simple User Control that lives in another directory and is loaded dynamically at runtime. Further assume that you truly dynamically want to load this control so you may have a choice of several controls, or the end-user might even create a custom control that gets dropped into place instead.

If you run the code above in ASP.NET 2.0 it will likely fail. I say likely because there are some inconsistencies that will sometimes pick up control references automatically, for example if the user control lives in the same directory and gets compiled into the same assembly as the page, or if another page has the control referenced.

It should and usually will fail. Why? Because ASP.NET compiles on a directory level and the CustomUserControl lives in a separate directory and so goes into a separate assembly. It’s not visible to page class to get a strongly typed reference. Intellisense will show a big, fat and red exclamation point or nothing at all for the MessageDisplay control. When you run the page it will bomb.

You can reference the control as the Control type of course, but if you need to access any custom properties on the user control beyond Control properties you can’t unless you resort to Reflection. As far as I know there’s no way to add a reference to another user control or page programmatically because the reference needs to be available way earlier at compile time before your code ever runs.

Alternatives are to not load controls dynamically or at least provide some mechanism to load up any user controls beforehand on a page with the appropriate @Register tags. But that’s not always possible. The other option is to create a user control base class in APP_CODE and expose the public interface there. The main problem with this is that this base class will not have access to any internal controls of the user control and so the base class would have to use FindControl to reference any embedded controls. So this is inefficient as hell, and cumbersome to boot.

I’ve run into similar situations with inheritance scenarios. For example, inheriting one master page off another’s CodeBeside class. All works well, but the ASP.NET compiler complains that the Profile object is being overridden illegally (a compiler warning). Running with the inherited master page works, but there are quirks. User Controls added to the master page often fail with type conflicts as ASP.NET treats the user control added to the base page as a different type than the user control added to the second page.

It’s inconsistencies like these that deal with referencing other types that have made me waste an incredible amount of time, thinking I had something fixed only to find out later that it didn’t actually work consistently when I changed a completely different page. Worse you have to really understand the model to get your head around what might be wrong.

Bottom line: The overall ASP.NET 2.0 compilation model is internally complex. Most of the time you don’t need to understand it, but when you run into these boundary scenarios, you really DO have to understand what goes on behind the scenes to be able to work around the quirks.

Comment: Could you summarize the article, in case link rot sets in and so people don't _have_ to follow a link?

Comment: I don't see a way to summarize it, you kind of have to read the entire article if you are fairly new to ASP.NET. I know you know this, but it's the entire magic behind ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you.  I've read Rick's stuff before and he knows ASP.Net like the back of his hand.